# Ionic 3 updated APK publishing failed

Tags: ionic-framework

After uploading updated APK to play store I see this error message:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnxnk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Publishing Apk

Step 1. Create Keystore (keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000)

Step 2. build apk (ionic cordova build android --prod --release)

Step 3. jarsign the unsigned apk using the keystore (jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore YOU_KEYSTORE.keystore android-release-unsigned.apk YOUR_APK_NAME)

Step 4. Zipalign the unsigned apk ( /home/USER_NAME/Android/Sdk/build-tools/25.0.2/zipalign -v 4 android-release-unsigned.apk YOUR_APK_NAME.apk )

Comment: Thank for answer. But error is still. I want update existing app already published in google play. ERROR "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle with invalid or missing signing information for some of its files. You need to create a valid signed APK or Android App Bundle. Learn more about signing."

Comment: Faced that problem before, try rebuilding and upload again

Comment: as you said 1. ionic cordova build --release android 2. jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore greasemonkeyapp.keystore app-release.apk greasemonkeyapp 3. zipalign -v 4 app-release.apk

Comment: Tanks you support. Yes, I followed this steps but I cant understand whats wrong. "You uploaded an APK or Android App Bundle with invalid or missing signing information for some of its files. You need to create a valid signed APK or Android App Bundle"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to upload unsigned apk to play store so you are getting this error.

Please create a singed apk with your keystore or jks then upload to play tore.

Comment: App already exist. But I want add some updates. I flowed this steps. 1. ionic cordova build --release android

2. jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore greasemonkeyapp.keystore app-release.apk greasemonkeyapp

3. zipalign -v 4 app-release.apk greasemonkey.apk      But error display in playstore

Answer (score 0):

try to add a file under platforms/android called release-signing.properties. Than fill out the data. With this the apk will be signed during every build.

```
storeFile=../../keystore/yourkeystore.keystore
storeType=jks
keyAlias=yourAlias
keyPassword=yourPassword
storePassword=yourStorePassword
```

If it's still not working than you signed the apk in the play store with a different key.

Comment: I want add some changes for my existing app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update your app then you need to sign your application with keytool you used for the initial release using that only you can update your application. Please sign the unsigned apk using the previous keytool and try to upload that apk in playstore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your support. problem is solved now. I deleted both **.jks** file and **release-signing.properties** from dir and created unsigned apk again. 
I suppose the problem is signing two times APK.